# Generating a list of slides in a text box alike to hyperlinks to specific slide in Google Presentation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am using Google Presentations very often, and I lack the ability to organize my slides. I would like to develop simple script that would put a list of slides. It would look exactly like the one we have when inserting hyperlinks to a specific slide. Is it doable? I have made a few newbie codes in Google Spreadsheet to make my work more efficient, but can it be done in Google Presentations?

Best

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is currently no access to Google Presentations through Google Apps Script.  I've found it in the issue tracker.  You may want to star it to add your vote to a feature request. [Issue 1573](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1573).